# Report Builder 3.0 and Gauges

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, dashboard

I have added 3 gauges to layout.  They are lined up next to each other.  However, when I run the report, the gauge on the right is to the far right of the report while the left and center gauge remain side by side.  Is there some property that needs to be change?  Any suggestions?  Thanks for the help.....